# How to fix the black block on VS Code's terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Does anyone know how to fix the black block on the terminal of VS Code?

When I open it, a black block appears, but if you click on it, it has text.

[image: example]

It was all fine, until the morning when I opened it.